# Spring-boot property value used in another property key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, application.properties

In my spring boot project, I want to use a property value in another property key:

```
server.mode=mock

server.protocol.mock=http
server.host.mock=my.host-mock.org
...

server.protocol.prod=https
server.host.prod=my.host-prod.org
...
```

I want to depending on "server.mode" value use the related property key server.protocol.{value}

How could I do this?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You can use spring profiles, where you can setup different property configurations for different deployment environments.

Using property files, you can create a property file per profile and then have spring boot use the right property configuration depending on the active profile.

[image: project structure]

`application-dev.properties`

```
server.scheme=http
server.host=my.host-mock.org
```

`application-prod.properties`

```
server.scheme=http
server.host=my.host-mock.org
```

You would then have to tell spring boot which profile to use by setting it in the `spring.profiles.active` property. When deploying to the cloud with application manifests (like Cloud Foundry or Kubernetes), then it is convenient to set this via an environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`.

See the official [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles) for more information about profiles.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the following format while fetching the value in code (or the correpsonding xml) where you are using it:

```
@Value("${server.protocol.${server.mode}}")
private String mode;
```